# LogMeIn Central not tracking Anti-Virus

Tags: anti-virus, logmein, sophos

We've been using LogMeIn to manage our PCs within our office (250+).

After a LogMeIn update, LogMeIn central has completely stopped tracking the version of Sophos we run in our office.

As a result of this there may be PCs within our office not running an AV.

After some testing we've discovered a re-install of LogMeIn on the clients PC re-enables virus tracking.

The only issue is - once we did a reinstall of LogMeIn, the client requires you to manually enter in the LogMeIn central details otherwise they are considered offline.

Is there any way we can mass deploy a LogMeIn installer to each of our users silently and without having to re-enter details?

Comment: I would contact LogMeIn technical support for a solution.  I have far to many questions, that I would require an answer to, you are better off just going directly to the source.

Comment: I've tried - they're bloody hopeless!